# Seleccionar columnas de un DataFrame usando una variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Para construir un histograma, utilizo sentencias de este tipo

```
dfmes_returns.Ibex_35.hist(bins=50,alpha=0.5, label = nom_val)
```

En esta sentencia, `"Ibex_35"` es un string contenido en una variable denominada `nom_ind`.

Si sustituyo el nombre por el nombre de la variable,

```
dfmes_returns.nom_ind.hist(bins=50,alpha=0.5, label = nom_val)
```

me devuelve el error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'nom_ind'

Dado que en la ejecución de sentencias del script anteriores a ésta,  el nombre almacenado en la variable `"nom_ind"`, puede cambiar, ¿Cómo podría modificar esta sentencia para que asocie automáticamente el nuevo nombre al atributo del dataframe?.

Agradeceré vuestra ayuda.

Efectivamente, "Ibex_35" es el nobre de una de las columnas del dataframe y para acceder a los valores de una columna de un dataframe, se puede hacer, como bien indica J. Sevilla, de varias maneras maneras.

```
dfmes_returns["Avantage"]
dfmes_returns.iloc[:, 0]
dfmes_returns.Avantage
```

Utilizando la variable tendríamos:

```
dfmes_returns[nom_ind].hist(bins=50,alpha=0.5, label = nom_val)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En vez de intentar acceder a la columna como atributo del objeto, se debe usar la variable para indizar sobre el DataFrame mediante `[]` (`__getitem__`):

```
nom_val = "Ibex_35"
dfmes_returns[nom_val].hist(bins=50, alpha=0.5, label=nom_val)
```

o también, usando `loc`, aunque en este caso no es necesario:

```
nom_val = "Ibex_35"
dfmes_returns.loc[:, nom_val].hist(bins=50,alpha=0.5, label=nom_val)
```

Si en vez de una variable se diera el caso de tener varias, o una variable con una lista de nombres:

```
nom_val1 = "Nasdaq"
nom_val2 = "Ibex_35"
dfmes_returns[[nom_val1, nom_val2]].hist(bins=50, alpha=0.5,
                                         label=[nom_val1, nom_val2]
                                         )
dfmes_returns.loc[:, [nom_val1, nom_val2]].hist(bins=50, alpha=0.5,
                                                label=[nom_val1, nom_val2]
                                                )


noms_vals = ["Ibex_35", "Nasdaq"]
dfmes_returns[noms_vals].hist(bins=50, alpha=0.5, label=noms_vals)
dfmes_returns.loc[:, noms_vals].hist(bins=50, alpha=0.5, label=noms_vals)
```

---

Como en cualquier otro objeto Python, la forma genérica de acceder a un atributo mediante una cadena con su nombre es usar el built-in `getattr`:

```
getattr(dfmes_returns, nom_val,).hist(bins=50, alpha=0.5, label=nom_val)
```

No obstante, en este caso no es nada recomendable, más cuando el indizado es más simple, más legible y mucho más robusto.

Comment: Efectivamente, "Ibex_35" es el nobre de una de las columnas del dataframe y para acceder a los valores de una columna de un dataframe, se puede hacer de varias, como bien indicas,  maneras.

Comment: Efectivamente, "Ibex_35" es el nobre de una de las columnas del dataframe y para acceder a los valores de una columna de un dataframe, se puede hacer de varias, como bien indicas. Se me habia ido el santo al cielo. Por otro lado, el caso de dos o más variables que apuntas, es muy útil para, por ejemplo, superponer y comparar dos histagrams. Muchas gracias.